# Vue.js: Monitor Dynamic Changes To Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Problem**

Changes to an object are not being detected by the listening child component.

**Context**

I have an empty object that is storing values as they come back from an API. This object is bound to a property in a child component.

```
data () {
  return {
    filterOperators: {}
  };
},
```

Each time this method is called, a named array containing the response is added to the object.

```
getfilterOperators: function (fieldName) {
  this.filterOperatorsAction(fieldName, response => {
    this.$data.filterOperators[fieldName] = response.Data;
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  Can you provide a jsFiddle that highlights the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Vue 1, it should be constructed like this in order to allow Vue to detect the change to the object:

```
this.$set('filterOperators.' + fieldName, response.data);
```

Reference: [Reactivity in Depth](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

In VueJS, properties added to objects are not reactive. You need to use the `vm.$set` method to make them reactive:

```
getfilterOperators: function (fieldName) {
  this.filterOperatorsAction(fieldName, response => {
    this.$set(this.filterOperators,fieldName,response.data);
  });
}
```

You can read more information on this page: [Reactivity in Depth](http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: Hm. It fails with a message of `TypeError: exp.trim is not a function. (In 'exp.trim()', 'exp.trim' is undefined)`. I also tried `this.$set(this.$data.filterOperators, sFieldName, response.Data);` with no success.